# What is this type of Apex statement called?

Tags: apex

```
Id parentId = (matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) ? matchingAccounts[0].PersonContactId : null;
```

I know it populates parentId with matchingAccounts[0], but where can I read more about this kind of statement?

I've never known you can check conditionals while assigning variables, which I assume is what the first part is doing.

My questions:

- What is this type of statement called?
- Where can I read more documentation and examples of its use?
- What does the null do at the end after the colon?
- What is the purpose of the question mark?

Comment: Ternary operator is [not specific to Apex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for letting me know. First I've ever seen it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a **ternary conditional operation**, which acts as short hand for an if-then-else statement.

Ternary operators can be great time savers. They take 3 params:

```
(condition) ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse;
```

A condition that evaluates to true/false

Result if true
Result if false

The syntax is as follows:

```
x ? y : z
```

and can be read as: if x, a Boolean, is true, then the result is y; otherwise it is z. Execute the following:

```
Boolean isIt = true;

String x = 'You are  ' + (isIt ?  'great' : 'small');

System.debug(x);
```

The resulting string has the value '**You are great**'.

[References](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.ch/2014/11/apex-ternary-operator-and-types.html)

Comment: To be precise, the ternary *operator* takes three *operands* to form a conditional *expression*.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add where in the standard docs this expression syntax is referenced. See [Understanding Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm):

```
Operator  |  Syntax     |  Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
? :       |  x ? y : z  |  Ternary operator (Right associative). This operator acts as a
                           short-hand for if-then-else statements. If x, a Boolean, is
                           true, y is the result. Otherwise z is the result. Note that x
                           cannot be null.
```

This expression syntax is ubiquitous in programming languages (though not contained in all, and differently expressed in some). Here is the MDN documentation on how the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) works in Javascript:

> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> condition ? expr1 : expr2
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `condition`
> An expression that evaluates to true or false.
>
> `expr1`, `expr2`
> Expressions with values of any type.
>
> ## Description
>
> If `condition` is true, the operator returns the value of `expr1`; otherwise, it returns the value of `expr2`. For example, to display a different message based on the value of the isMember variable, you could use this statement:
>
> ```
> "The fee is " + (isMember ? "$2.00" : "$10.00")
> ```

The syntax is very slightly different in this example (single-quotes only in `Apex`, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

This statement is called Ternary operator. Its working on `if-else` functionality. If you want known the Apex ternary operator [Click Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm). In this statement working on

```
Id parentId = (matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) ? matchingAccounts[0].PersonContactId : null;
```

In this code is converted into given logic

```
Id parentId;

if(matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) {

   parentId = matchingAccounts[0].PersonContactId;

} else {

   parentId = null;
}
```

In this logic is simplify use of ternary operator.

Devendra is answered with great example to ternary operator.